# Navigate to latitude, longitude point via Navigation Content URI?

Tags: java, android, navigation, gps

Is there a URI used by the Navigation application to go to a specific latitude, longitude point? Or is this limited to only to an address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. There are no documented and supported `Intents` or `Uri` values to use for Google Navigation. [You can get to Google Maps](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html), and from there the user can choose to enter Navigation, but that's it.